# Diacritic insensitive search in PDFDocument

Tags: ios, swift, ios-pdfkit

Using PDFKit, I'd like to perform diacritic insensitive search in a PDFDocument. I tried to add the [diacriticInsensitive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1412313-diacriticinsensitive) compare options in my call [beginFindString(_:withOptions:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436078-beginfindstring), but it seems to be ignored.

```
document.beginFindString(text, withOptions: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive])
```

This code give's me only case insensitive results, which is kind of frustating.

Is there a way to make diacritic insensitive search working in PDFKit ? Or is this option not available (perhaps for performance issues) ?